# Feed literal string bash variable to awk and gsub

Tags: bash, awk, gsub

I want to edit a column in a text file by feeding a bash variable containing a literal string to awk and gsub

I have tried various version of the command below. It works for a variable that does not contain any special characters but not for one that needs to be interpreted as a literal string.

```
#create intial file
echo -e "SOD1:c.112G>A(p.[G38R])"'\t'"SOD1:c.112G>A(p.[G38R]);NA" > testfile 

#set variable
var="SOD1:c.112G>A(p.[G38R])"

#test awk
more testfile | awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' -v var="${var}" '{gsub(var,"",$2)}1'
```

I want to delete the variable only in the second column not in the first.
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I don't know if you have any better option than quoting the special characters. Setting var as `$ export var='SOD1:c.112G>A\\(p\\.\\[G38R\\]\\)'` works with your test awk. (Note the single quotes on the right hand side of the assignment .)

Comment: @jas you should post your comment as answer, I test it and it works :D

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. Hmm it needs to be done for many variables that are automatically set as part of a larger script, so I may have to look for a new way to go about it. Thanks though!

Comment: try `-v var="'${var}'"`  If it doesn't work like that, then append `'` chars to `$2` inside of `awk`. Hmm, that will get ugly. There is a way to assign `'` to a variable in awk, maybe as an ASCII value, but I don't have the time to search for that. Good luck.

Comment: See `gsub_literal` in [BashFAQ #21](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021), as preexisting, already-working code that does *exactly* what you're aiming for.

Answer (score 1):

You can just put your `var` definition and your awk command in one line like this:

```sh
var='SOD1:c.112G>A\(p.\[G38R\]\)'; awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' -v var="$var" '{gsub(var,"",$2)}1'  testfile
```